# What is the safe alternative to realpath()?

Tags: c++, c

I am working on a program which uses realpath() to get the absolute path of a file. Unfortunately, this function takes a string buffer that is expected to be so large that it is big enough and that's not safe when this application has to run across multiple platforms. Is there a safe version of this function which avoids the buffer overflow issue, perhaps using dynamic memory allocation?

Answer (score 20):

See here for information on safe and portable use of `realpath`:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html

Basically, modern standards allow you to pass a NULL pointer, and `realpath` will allocate a buffer of the appropriate length. If you want to be portable to legacy systems which do not support this standard, simply check `#ifdef PATH_MAX` and use a fixed-size buffer of length `PATH_MAX`. As far as I know, there are no legacy systems that lack a constant `PATH_MAX` but which do not support NULL arguments to `realpath`.

Comment: Remember to include <limits.h> before checking for PATH_MAX, otherwise it won't be defined.

Answer (score 14):

From the manpage:

> If  resolved_path  is  specified  as 
>   NULL,  then realpath() uses malloc(3)
>   to allocate a buffer of up to PATH_MAX
>   bytes to hold the resolved pathname,
>   and returns a pointer to this buffer. 
>   The caller should deallocate this
>   buffer using free(3).buffer using free(3).

So it seems like you can just do this:

```
char *real_path = realpath(path, NULL);
// use real_path
free(real_path);
```

Comment: This is standard behavior as of POSIX 2008, but I believe it was a GNU extension in the past. See my answer for a slightly more portable approach.

Comment: @R..: good point, I wasn't aware that particular detail was relatively new.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do the same in Boost using [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

try{
    path absolutePath = canonical("./../xxx"); //will throw exception if file not exists!

}
catch{...}{
    cout << "File not exists";
}
cout << absolutePath.string();
```

There is QT way to do it (got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544790/how-to-get-directory-of-a-file-which-is-called-from-command-line-argument)):

```
QFileInfo target_file_name(argv[1]);
QString absolute_path = target_file_name.absolutePath()
```

There is a bit complicated [implementation of realpath in C++](http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/implementing-realpath-in-c.html). Cannot tell anything about it's safety, but it should allow path with length more then `PATH_MAX`. Going to test it soon.

Comment: `absolutePath` is not visible outside `try/catch`